# How to get all fields from Get-ADUser?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the following code:

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -Server $Domain -ResultPageSize 500000 -Filter * -Properties *, "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" |
         Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty *Certificate, PropertyNames,
             *Properties, PropertyCount, Certificates, nTSecurityDescriptor
foreach ($U in $Users) {
    $($U.PSobject.Properties.Name).Count
}
```

When you check count of properties for each object, it will be different. In the case of my test domain, this ranges from 103 to 147 properties per object.

While I can always add that count to an array, sort of like this:

```
$Array = @()
foreach ($T in $Test) {
    #Get-ObjectType $T
    $Array += $($T.PSobject.Properties.Name).Count
}

$Array | Sort-Object
```

And take the highest value and take all named properties from the one with highest properties count and then build my Excel/Word/SQL object based on that... there is:

1. a chance that the object with highest number of properties count doesn't really have the same properties like the one with the lowest number of properties
2. a big performance hit (I know that asking for all fields is a performance hit anyway)

Is there some other way to get a full set of results with all fields listed, even if they are empty for some records?

If you're wondering why I may need this think of creating a SQL table that will need all fields defined prior to inserting rows. Or an Excel workbook that will go row by row starting with header (which has to be known).

Comment: This sounds like something that should be addressed with whoever created the AD user schema, not so much with a catch-all powershell script.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? It's clean AD 2016 + Exchange 2013 installed. It's just how it is. The schema has nothing to do with it. Each object returns only data that is "set". If it's not set it's not returned it seems. So I'm looking for a way to ask for all data. Whether it has that data or not.

Comment: It's always been that way with AD. If the attribute isn't set it isn't returned. May help if you describe the end goal

Comment: @RichardSiddaway The solution to this is this https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2017/09/22/one-liner-query-the-ad-schema-for-user-object-attributes/ the end goal.. https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWinDocumentation is getting this into perfect state

Comment: @RichardSiddaway and this https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteExcel and https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteWord. Both get object and put it into the table. For proper header in a table I need to know all fields that there may be in an object.

Comment: If you want all possible properties, you're better off querying the AD schema itself, not particular objects in the schema. [See also](http://blog.goverco.com/2013/09/use-powershell-to-get-ad-schema.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opted for this approach:

```
function Get-ObjectProperties {
param (
    [object] $Object
)
    $Properties = New-ArrayList
    foreach ($O in $Object) {
        $ObjectProperties = $O.PSObject.Properties.Name
        foreach ($Property in $ObjectProperties) {
            Add-ToArrayAdvanced -List $Properties -Element $Property -SkipNull -RequireUnique
        }
   }
   return $Properties | Sort-Object
}
```

I've added it to `PSSharedGoods` module (`Install-Module PSSharedGoods`) as I also use `New-ArrayList`, `Add-ToArrayAdvanced` functions that I've added into that module. It can be probably done without those additional functions but since I already use them a lot I don't mind.

I've tried other stuff like:

```
$properties = Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).SchemanamingContext -Filter {name -eq "User"} -Properties MayContain, SystemMayContain | `
    Select-Object @{name = "Properties"; expression = {$_.maycontain + $_.systemmaycontain}} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Properties

$Test1 = Get-ADUser -Server $Domain -ResultPageSize 5000000 -Filter * -Properties $properties
```

Or:

```
$Test1 = Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).SchemaNamingContext -Filter {name -like "User"} -Properties MayContain, SystemMayContain |
    Select-Object @{n = "Attributes"; e = {$_.maycontain + $_.systemmaycontain}} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Attributes | Sort-Object

$Test2 = Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).SchemaNamingContext -ldapfilter '(systemFlags:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=4)' -Properties systemFlags |
    Select-Object Name | Sort-Object Name
```

But it simply doesn't return everything. The method I used on my simple domain returned 181 properties (from my function). Other methods returned 43 or similar. It still doesn't return everything but it's better than what I had before. For example it returns `ExtensionAttribute10` but not others but that's because only 1 object in my AD has that set.

I am not sure how I could be sure to get all possible fields available.